# Establishing a simple websocket handshake

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

Client:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8183/websession');
        socket.onopen = function () {
            alert('handshake successfully established. May send data now...');
        };
        socket.onclose = function () {
            alert('connection closed');
        };
</script>
```

server:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Net.Sockets;
 using System.Net;
 using System.IO;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8183);
        listener.Start();
        using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        using (var stream = client.GetStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
            writer.WriteLine("Upgrade: WebSocket");
            writer.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
            writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:8092");
            writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8183/websession");
            writer.WriteLine("");
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

the problem is that the connection is never established and the onopen function is never called what may be the problem ?

Comment: what do you suggest ? what should i use ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's not true; a web-socket is **absolutely** a TCP socket, and you absolutely **can** implement web-sockets over `TcpListener`. Personally I'd use a naked `Socket` / `Stream`, though. I know this *because I wrote the web-socket server that we use at Stack Exchange*. which is ... kinda busy.

Comment: so @MarcGravell can you please tell me why my code is not working ?

Comment: @Sora working on it ;p answer is in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your "server" seems to be sending the "client" part of the handshake. Secondly, `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` ***will not help you much***; frankly, you would do well just to use the `Stream`.

Now, the actual handshake is complicated; both client and server need to prove to each-other than they are actually talking web-sockets, and not HTTP. The exact nature of this depends on the version of the protocol you are trying to support (or multiple protocols), but the *server* is required to perform a maths calculation based on the headers that the *client* sends; the server sends the answer back in *its* headers, and this checks that they are talking the same language. Note that this is **not** a security step: it is a sanity protection step. This is all described in the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), but an example request / response pair is (from that document):

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

And:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

After which, it drops from HTTP into web-socket protocol, which is binary and unrelated to HTTP. For info, `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` is the result of the maths calculation, based on the client's `Sec-WebSocket-Key`.

The next bit of code that you will need is frame support. Again - see the specification. Also keep in mind that this specification is **just version 13**. If you want to support all clients, you might need to check the older specifications too (there are some subtle tweaks, except for the *original original* protocol, which was radically different and will require completely different code).

Before writing all this, you might want to look into whether a pre-existing library would be more practical. Windows 8 (and similar versions of server) include web-socket supprt direct in HTTP.SYS, with full support in .NET.

Comment: i read your reply and i saw the specification link but i am still can't figure out how should i fix my code to accomplish the connection

Comment: @Sora by implementing the web-sockets protocol and sending the correct response headers; and then implementing the frames; this **is not trivial code**. I can't give you an estimate on "how long" because a: I don't know how familiar you are with binary protocols, and b: I don't know many clients this server needs to support (which can change the design significantly). But at a *minimum* this is going to be a solid day's coding. Hence I can't really include all that in a reply here. Except to say: please consider using an existing library unless you really really need it done manually.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and hard work and thank you for your reply i will take what you said under consideration by reading more about websockets and how to implement them